# router.use middleware does not get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, token, jwt

I have a simple server application running with NodeJS, and I tried to implement the route protecting that is in [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) tutorial, I already have the token that works every time I login.

So this middleware should be called to all routes except register and login. So I did this in my initial setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var debug = require('debug')('express-sequelize');
var http = require('http');
var models = require('./models');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwtPermission = require('./controller/jwtPermission');
var fotos = require('./routes/fotos');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



  app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));
   app.use(jwtPermission);
   app.use('/fotos',fotos);
```

The middleware that doesn't get called is **jwtPermission**. So I have a routes folder where I have a index, and the authentication file(that has login and register). For the jwtPermission I just have the controller set as you guys can see.

I have a console.log inside that controller but it never gets called.

**jwtPermission**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwtConfig = require('../config/jwt');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("entered");

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
          console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token,jwtConfig.secret, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure your routes in the `Route` object, but you have to attach it in your `app` object.

So, in this case, change `route.use` to `app.use`.

Don't need to use the route object.

Comment: thank you for the answer, why i can't do it with route? can you explain me?

Comment: Actually, you can. But in your cause using the router wasn't necessary. But if you really do it in that way, you could just attach the `router` in the `app` in the end. Like this: `app.use(router);`

Comment: hey leandro still there, i have the same problem then yersterday, i changed everything to app.use but the jwtPermission just works if i put it before the app.use(the authentication one), any suggestion, thanks :D

Comment: did it, if i put that permission before the '/' app.use it works, but for all routes even authentication i just want that to execute for all routes except authentication